# Django - exception handling

Tags: python, django

I'm having this error page in Django.

```
Exception Type: IndexError
Exception Value: list index out of range
Exception Location: /home/nirmal/try/portfolio/views.py in vimeo_authorize, line 52
```

What I need is I just want to except this error in my views. I tried like this:

```
try:
       .........
except IndexError:
       .........
```

But it is not working. Could anyone give me the correct code?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to provide more details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That code is correct. You're putting it in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

A 'list index out of range' error is pretty basic in Python, as is exception handling, which you should reference the docs for:

- http://docs.python.org
- http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types
- http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html

In any case, a 'list index out of range' error means you're trying to get a specific index on an iterable that doesn't exist, for example this code:

```
mylist = [1,2,3,4]
print mylist[57]
```

... would throw that error, because only indexes 0 - 3 have been created and I am trying to access 57. To handle this exception, you would do something like:

```
try:
    item = mylist[57]
except IndexError:
    # Do some other stuff if we don't find the index we want...
    item = None
```

Comment: @Tadeck Why is that a bad thing? It was my impression that handling specific Exception types is there if you want to handle those cases distinctly.

Comment: Exactly! "_handling specific Exception types_" is there and if you want to handle the exception of index being out of range, you should catch only the exception you want to handle (`IndexError`). Otherwise you will not catch other exceptions, thus you will not be able to tell, whether there is something else wrong with your code. Just by the way: there is some interesting anti-pattern called [Diaper Antipattern](http://mike.pirnat.com/2009/05/09/the-diaper-pattern-stinks/).